# Remove substring from front and back of variable

Tags: bash, string

I know that I can remove substrings from the front of a variable:

```
X=foobarbaz
echo ${X#foo}       # barbaz
```

...and from the back of a variable:

```
echo ${X%baz}       # foobar
```

How do I combine the two? I've tried:

```
echo ${{X#foo}%baz}    # "bad substitution"
echo ${${X#foo}%baz}   # "bad substitution"
echo ${X#foo%baz}      # foobarbaz
```

I don't *think* I can use an intermediate variable, because this is being used in `find -exec`, in something like the following:

```
find ./Source -name '*.src' \
    -exec bash -c 'myconvert -i "{}" -o "./Dest/${0#./Source/%.src}.dst"' {} \;
```

Comment: Could the inner brace be an _alias_ ? I'm not so good with Bash aliases.

Comment: Note, before bash had such string manipulation we used **expr** (which uses an anchored regexp not globs). Eg `expr "foobarbaz" : 'foo\(.*\)baz$'` returns the captured "bar".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think that's possible (but would love to be proved wrong). However, you can use an intermediate variable. The `bash -c` run by `-exec` is just a bash instance, like any other:

```
$ find . -type f
./foobarbaz
$ find . -type f -exec bash -c 'v=${0#./foo}; echo ${v%baz}'  {} \;
bar
```

So I see no reason why this wouldn't work (if I understood what you're trying to do correctly):

```
find ./Source -name '*.src' \
     -exec bash -c 'v=${0%.src}; \ 
        myconvert -i "{}" -o "./Dest/${v#./Source/}.dst"' {} \;
```

Answer (score 8):

The usual way is to do it in two steps:

```
x=foobarbaz
y=${x#foo}       # barbaz
z=${y%baz}       # bar
```

As this are "Parameter Expansions", a "Parameter" (variable) is needed to be able to perform any substitution. That means that y and z are needed. Even if they could be the same variable:

```
x=foobarbaz
x=${x#foo}       # barbaz
x=${x%baz}       # bar
```

---

```
find ./Source/ -name '*.src' -exec \
    bash -c '
        x=${1#./Source/}
        myconvert -i "$1" -o "./Dest/${x%.src}.dst"
    ' shname {} \;
```

Where `shname` is parameter `$0` and the next `{}` is parameter `$1` to the bash call.

---

A simpler alternative is to do a `cd ./Source` at the begining to avoid removing that part later. Something like:

```
cd ./Source                 ### Maybe test that it exist before cd to it.
shopt -s extglob nullglob   ### Make sure that correct options are set.

for f in *.src **/*.src; do
    echo \
    myconvert -i "$f" -o "./Dest/${f%.src}.dst"
done
```

Once you are convinced that it does what you want, comment out the echo.

Answer (score 2):

I always do it one step at a time:

```
X=foobarbaz; X="${X#foo}"; X="${X%baz}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method, relative to the OP's concept, is to use `sed`.

For example, if you have a filename format like this:

> /music/artist/album

And you wish to extract "artist", this will work:

```
filename="/music/artist/album"
sed -nr 's/.*\/(.*)\/.*/\1/p' <<< "$filename"
```

Returns:

> artist

In the example above, `sed` isolates the middle sub-string by removing everything left and right of the first pattern bounded by a '/' character on either side. The delimiters are also removed.

Note that `sed` begins dissecting the string from *right to left*. Therefore, it doesn't matter if your filename path in this illustration begins with `/` or not. For instance, it returns the same result ("artist") for either of these paths:

> /music/artist/album
>
> music/artist/album

**About the command line**

-n limits the output to one iteration

-r allows the use of a regex expression
/p tells sed to print the result

Also, you may prefer this slightly shorter version of the command (though it is less explicit):

```
sed -r 's/.*\/(.*)\/.*/\1/' <<< "$filename"
```

If you want to use a different character or string as boundary delimiters, change the character(s) in the position where you see the '**X**' below:

```
sed -nr 's/.*\X(.*)\X.*/\1/p' <<< "$test"
```

..........................^.........^

Comment: With boundary delimiters you mean the slashes here: /music/artist/album ? You cannot replace them because they are given..

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised this hasn't been suggested yet, but Bash [substring expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) would have done this for you. If the length of the prefix and suffix are already known, you can simply do:

```
X=foobarbaz
echo ${X:3:-3}
# output: bar
```

If the prefix and suffix are variables, you'll have to use the POSIX-standard [string length expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) to get the offsets:

```
X=foobarbaz
prefix=fo
suffix=az
echo ${X:${#prefix}:-${#suffix}}
# output: obarb
```